# Accessing public static final field using JoSQL

Tags: josql

I've been using JoSQL for quite a few months now and today I came across a problem I am not sure how to solve. I probably could solve it by binding variables/placeholders, but I'd like to include the fields in the query.

SELECT * FROM ...MyObject WHERE getType != com.mypackage.myclass.TYPE_A

This is the query that I have. TYPE_A is a public static final int attribute in "myclass" class. Accessing methods (such as getType) is easy, because getType is expected to be a method from MyObject - just that I do not write round brackets after it (this is how JoSQL works as far as I know).

Does anyone happen to have an idea how to access a public static final field?

JoSQL uses gentlyweb-utils; it seems to be some sort of Accessor/Getter/Setter framework. I'd love to access that attribute without having to bind variables, but I haven't been able to do so.

Thanks for your help in advance! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured something out. First: it seems not possible to access the static variables for whatever reason. I've used the following approach to solve my issue:

1. create a method, which picks up a given JoSQL-statement
2. mark the constants, which you want to replace, by say "{?FULL_PACKAGE_AND$CONSTANT}"
3. use reflections to determine the column as well as the column (and value) from the field
4. iteratively replace the statement until no "{?"-values are available

**Example:**
*JoSQL-statement looks like this:*

```
(isWeapon = TRUE AND getItem.getType2 = {?com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.items.L2Item$TYPE2_WEAPON})
```

Method using the query-object:

```
final Query query = DataLayer.createJoSqlQuery(joSql);
```

Method (pre)processing the JoSQL-statement:

```
final Query query = new Query();

int variableColumn = 0;
while (joSql.indexOf("{?") > -1) {
    variableColumn++;
    final int startIndex = joSql.indexOf("{?");
    final int endIndex = joSql.indexOf("}", startIndex);
    final String value = joSql.substring(startIndex + 2, endIndex);
    try {
        final Object variableValue = Class.forName(value.split("\\$")[0]).getField(value.split("\\$")[1]).get(null);
        query.setVariable(variableColumn, variableValue);
        joSql = joSql.replace("{?" + value + "}", "?");
    }
    catch (...) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

query.parse(joSql);
return query;
```

The JoSQL-statement preprocessing method bascially iterates through a given JoSQL-statement and sees whether it contains the string "{?". If it does, it does some copy and paste (note the dollar-symbol right in front of the constant name).

Finally it creates the objects and sets them using something similar to prepared statements "setObject"-method. In the end it just replaces the values within the JoSQL-statement with question marks ("?") and sets a corresponding object in the newly created Query-object, which is later used to retrieve information.